# Printing better formating in command line

Tags: terminal, php

I have a php script that i run via command line like

```
php file.php
```

and in that file i have a print statement like

```
print "<br>Saved the url: {$url} to :{$destination}";
```

I assumed the br would formant it 1 below the other but when i run the script i get this format which is really hard to read

```
<br>Saved the url: http://example.com/a.mp3 to :/usr/recordings/3e/1555141317-2349577.mp3<br>Saved the url: http://example.com/b.mp3 to :/usr/recordings
```

so the formatting is really hard to read in the console. Is there a way to restructure my print to have the output like this

```
Saved the url: http://example.com/a.mp3 to :/usr/recordings/3e/1555141317-dadfdasffa.mp3
Saved the url: http://example.com/b.mp3 to :/usr/recordings/3c/1555141317-fddfd.mp3
Saved the url: http://example.com/c.mp3 to :/usr/recordings/3f/1555141317-ffdfd.mp3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a newline instead of br.

```
print "\nSaved the url: {$url} to :{$destination}";
```

If you want that to work with html output as well you can check which sapi you're running with:

```
echo PHP_SAPI == 'cli' ? PHP_EOL : '<br>', "Saved the url: {$url} to :{$destination}";
```

Comment: you can always do both if you don't mind the BRs in your output- `<br/>\n`

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Saved the url: {$url} to :{$destination}\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried \n\r or \n ? 
 is for html. Console is different.